# Problems with inserting image into table of blob type

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image, blob

Having problems with inserting image into table of blob type. If I insert it manually by phpmyadmin, and print it, I can get the image, but with this code I can't insert into table. On localhost it works, but on the server doesn't. Can you please help. I've already searched the forums, but couldn't get correct answer.
Here's the code:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  File:
                  <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="upload">
                </form>

                <?php 
                $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

                if(!isset($file))
                  echo "Please select some image";

                else 
                {
                  $image_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['name']);
                  $image = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));

                  $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);




                  if($image_size == FALSE)
                  {
                    echo "That's not an image";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    if (!$insert = mysql_query("insert into image(id, name, image) values ('','$image_name','$image')"))
                    {                                                        
                      echo "Problem uploading image";
                    }                       
                    else
                    {                                                      

                      $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image "); 
                      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
                      {
                        echo "<img src=data:image/jpeg;base64," . (base64_encode(($row['Image']))) . " style='width:60px;height:60px;'>";
                      }
                    }

                  }

                } 

                ?>
```

If I echo the $row['Image'] the result is like this: "?PNG  IHDR??vlH cHRMz%??????u0?`:?o?" and etc.

Comment: is your id field is auto-increment ?

Comment: what kind of data type in image field in your table

Comment: Since your `id` is `auto increment` field So try this `mysql_query("insert into image(name, Image) values ('$image_name','$image')")) `

Comment: `myslql_*` is deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: @Log1c but I don't know how to insert it with mysqli, that's why I use mysql

Comment: thats same thing, except it will ask for `$link_to_db` for almost all `mysqli_*` functions. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: can you please just echo query result so that we can help you some more

Comment: @SagarPanchal here you are: "Array ( [id] => 55 [name] => barca.png [image] => ?PNG  IHDR??vlH cHRMz%??????u0?"

Comment: it means image upload code works in a wrong manner

Comment: @SagarPanchal "Array ( [id] => 58 [name] => i-157.jpg [image] => ????JFIFHH??C !"$"$??C???X"?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in PDO

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=database_name;host=localhost', 'username', 'password',
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));

          $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
          $imageData = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
          $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);

          $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO image (name,image) VALUES (:name,:image)');
          $stmt->bindParam(':image', $imageData, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
          $stmt->bindParam(':name', $imageName);
          $stmt->execute(array('name' => $imageName, 'image' => $imageData));
          echo "Image Uploaded";


          $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image "); 
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
          {                                                  
            echo "<img src=data:image/jpeg;base64," . (base64_encode(($row['image']))) . " style='width:60px;height:60px;'>";
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not even used image_size in your so don't need to define it, and on other hand you are not storing the file path into db. first define file path of the image and then store it, else refer this [Reference site](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

and Update your query

```
("insert into image(id, name, Image) values (null,'$image_name','$image')")
```

Comment: i think the problem is not with id, updated still no result, the broken image's icon

Comment: now I can't even insert an image, "That's not an image"

Comment: you have remove this, and its related braces also `if($image_size == FALSE)
                  {
                    echo "That's not an image";
                  }
                  else
                  {`

Comment: my file path is like this: "Stored in: /tmp/phpiIkGuZImage"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not opening a database connection before querying

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","mysql_user","mysql_pwd");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
$query = "your query";
mysql_query($query,$con);
```

and also use

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

before `echo`ing the image.

Comment: i've connection to db, if i didn't have i couldn't insert into table

Comment: it inserts into table all of the rows: id, name, image. But when I try to show it, it just shows the broken image's icon, however it shows the image which was uploaded manually.

Comment: can u try this                                           _header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['Image'];_                                                        if the image is png do _image/png_

Comment: echo $row['Image'] shows "�PNG\r\n\Z\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0�\0\0�\0\0\0vlH\0\0\0 cHRM\0\0z%\0\0"

Comment: did u put header("Content-type: image/png"); before echoing?